# Permanently delete a row in base table family defined with keep_deleted_cells=true

Tags: hbase

I’ve got a table in hbase that has all column families defined with KEEP_DELETED_CELLS=True. In this way I have history up to a certain number of versions despite deletes.

However this makes the table in essence constantly growing as there’s no way to discard a row i no longer require with a simple delete.

I wonder does anyone know is there a way I could delete some rows permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about TTL?

Comment: To use ttl I need to know in advance when I can delete the row which is not the case for me. Another, hacky, option is to insert as many dummy versions (or possibly just tombstones?) as VERSIONS setting on the family with very short ttl to delete a row.